# Intellij incorrectly highlighting bracket pairs?

Tags: intellij-idea

For whatever reason, Intellij is highlighting the wrong bracket pair:

[Intellij highlighting wrong bracket pair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OscIQ.png)

Yet it works in any other text editor on the same exact code:

[Vim highlighting correct bracket pair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbRCv.png)

For almost every bracket, Intellij either highlights the wrong pair or doesn't highlight at all. This issue is unusual, so I'm not sure where to look into it. I've tried testing the bracket matching on all kinds of code in Intellij and it almost always highlights the wrong pair. I also reinstalled Intellij but that did not fix it. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.1 x64

Comment: I doubt this very much.  There's something wrong with your code.

Comment: I have this issue with any code I write, plus the code in the example runs as expected

Comment: Also, I just tried it in vim, and vim can match the bracket pairs correctly, but Intellij cannot.

Comment: I've used IntelliJ every day for the last 16 years.  It matches bracket pairs correctly.

Comment: I already figured this isn't a problem for everyone. But just because it works on your machine doesn't mean it works on mine. Hence why I'm asking the question.

Comment: I'm suggesting that IntelliJ isn't the problem.  It's your code.  Strip out all but the first pair of brackets and start adding them back in.

Comment: I updated my question's description, as I probably wasn't clear on the problem, but every text editor I test this issue on is able to correctly match bracket pairs on the exact same code, except for Intellij. So it's not a problem with my code, as much as I wish it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong. It turns out the reason this happens is because Intellij Community Edition doesn't support Javascript. So I installed the Ultimate Edition which does support Javascript, and it works now:

[Intellij Ultimate highlights bracket pair correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9bUm.png)